# Remove Ubuntu from computer

Tags: uninstall

I got a new laptop and I installed Ubuntu onto it. Before, there was no operating system.

Is there a way I can remove Ubuntu, and get back to having no operating system at all??

Answer (score 2):

yes, if you have `Ubuntu Live CD/DVD/USB` then you can remove everything from your hard-drive and make it as it was a new.

Follow these steps:

- Boot from your Ubuntu Live CD/DVD/USB
- Chose `Try Ubuntu` options instead of `Install Ubuntu`
- Once starts open `gparted` from your `dash` or open terminal (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) execute this:

  ```
  sudo gparted
  ```
- When `gparted` starts delete the partition where `Ubuntu` is installed or delete all partitions and make a new one.
- Shutdown your system from `Try Ubuntu` session.

Thats all.. You have removed each and every bit. Reply if you want further assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Boot a Live CD (such as the Ubuntu installation CD), and use a disk tool such as gparted to delete the partitions.  If there's something personal that you want to destroy first, use a program such as "shred" or "wipe"...

https://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/442455-wiping-your-disk-drive-clean